# LilyPond: melody guideline over a page break produces overlapping staves

Tags: lilypond

LilyPond produces strange, overlapping staves if a VoiceFollower crosses a page break. Consider the following code:

```
\version "2.24.3"
\language "italiano"

\paper {
    #(set-paper-size '(cons (* 195 mm) (* 120 mm)))
}

\score {
    \new PianoStaff <<
        \new Staff = "right" \relative do'' {
            <>
            \key re \minor
            \numericTimeSignature
            \time 3/4
            <<
                {
                    sold8-- (sol16 sold la4) r4
                    \pageBreak
                    \oneVoice
                    <sib re mi sol sib>8-> [
                    <la dod mi sol la>->
                    <fad do' re fad>->]
                    <sol, do! sol'>16-- [(la' <fad, do' fad>8--)] r8
                }\\
                {
                    re'4~ 16 dod (mi sol la dod mi sol)
                }\\
                {
                    s2 s8 s16
                    \change Staff = "left"
                    \stemDown
                    \hideNotes
                    la,
                    \override VoiceFollower.breakable = ##t
                    \showStaffSwitch
                    \once \omit Stem
                    \once \omit Flag
                    \change Staff = "right"
                    sib8
                    \hideStaffSwitch
                    \unHideNotes
                }
            >>
            <<
                {
                    r16 do' (sib la sol4~-- 8) la
                    \break
                    fa4~-- 8 sol (mib re)
                }\\
                {
                    r4 re,4 do~ 4 sib'8 lab sol4
                }
            >>
        }
        \new Staff = "left" \relative do {
            \key re \minor
            \clef bass
            <<
                {
                    fa4 (mi)
                }\\
                {
                    la,2
                }
            >>
            \clef treble
            dod'16 mi sol la
            <sol, re' mi sol>8_> [<la dod mi sol>_> \clef bass <re, la' re>_>]
            <la mib'>_- [<re, la' re>_- ] \clef treble
            la'''16 sib
            \mergeDifferentlyDottedOn
            <<
                {
                    do fad, sol la sib--
                    la sol la sol8 fa16 sol
                    la16-- sol fa sol <fa>4 r4
                }\\
                {
                    s16 fad8. fa4 mib~ 4
                    <re>8 do16 re mib re sib do
                }
            >>
        }
    >>
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

If you delete `\showStaffSwitch`, the result will be:
[image]

As a proof of concept, everything works as expected if you remove all extra breaks:
[image]

Comment: Known bug https://gitlab.com/lilypond/lilypond/-/issues/6551